# Flutter sqflite does not work on real devices android

Tags: flutter, sqflite

i have created project with sqflite library.
on emulator in my laptop. this is fine and work.

but when i "flutter build apk"
and i install in my phone real devices. it does not work.

```
static DatabaseHelper _dbHelper = DatabaseHelper._singleton();

  factory DatabaseHelper() {
    return _dbHelper;
  }

  DatabaseHelper._singleton();

  Future<Database> openDB() async {
    Directory dbPath = await path.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return sqlite.openDatabase(dbPath.path + '/dbagen.db',
        onCreate: _onCreate, version: 1);
  }

  Future<void> _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE p_task (
      idticket INT PRIMARY KEY,
      idprovider INT,
      tanggaladd TEXT
    )
    ''');
  }
```

please help!!
thanks!!

Comment: What part of your database is not working?

Comment: thats code totally working on emulator,
but when i install on real device it is not working

Comment: What do you mean as "not working"? It is not saving a data?

Comment: after debugging ,, the issue is not about sqflite, but access path to device. when create file DB.
`Directory dbPath = await path.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();`
or
`final dbPath2 = await getDatabasesPath();`

in emulator when i print. showing:
/data/user/0/com.example.agenpro

but in real device,, when i print to text,, its not showing anything

Comment: by the way thank you for your support
greeting from indonesia

Answer (score 0):

*THIS ISSUE HAS BEEN SOLVED*
in build.gradle add this to your buildTypes > release section
add

`shrinkResources false proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'`

after that create file in android/app/proguard-rules.pro
add this code

`-keep class io.flutter.plugin.editing.** { *; }`